# Can't Use wamp server anymore after installing SQL server

Tags: wamp

I Used `WAMP` and `Easy PHP` to test my php programs.

After installing Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 yesterday ,`WAMP Server and Easy PHP` are not working.

`Easy php` gives an error : `Port 80 used by system`, screenshot given below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlKyS.png

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your SQL server or IIS will be using port 80 . Try to disable / stop the service for the SQL server or IIS (any of those, i am not sure, but normally IIS uses port 80).

When you are using wamp / easy php, stop service for both of them.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes, but as i mentioned, when you need to run wamp , then stop those services. But whenever you need to use tham again, then start them again. There may be some other ways to use both of them at once, but i am not sure how. IIS and WAMP (Only Apache) both uses port 80, so you have to change the port for any one of them.

Comment: Thank You But How Can I Stop SQL Server?

Comment: As i am not using sql server and IIS, so i will be not able to give you exact services names. Go to control panel and then administrative Tools. Click on Services. You will have a complete list of services. Find out IIS and SQL server related services. Right click on them, and then click STOP. Using the same, you can start stopped services.

Comment: Also google a little bit, and you will find the exact way how to stop / start services for IIS and SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If 80 port is used by IIS server or system then you can change your Wamp Server port in this case.

If you want to stop IIS server then also it will work but which IIS version are you using , I don't know for IIS7 , you can refer this url given below

[Start and Stop IIS server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732317%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Click on the WAMP server icon and from the menu under Config Files select httpd.conf. A long text file will open up in notepad. In this file scroll down to the line that reads Port 80 and change this to read Port 8080, Save the file and close notepad. Once again click on the wamp server icon and select restart all services. One more change needs to be made before we are done. In Windows Explorer find the location where WAMP server was installed which is by Default C:\Wamp.

**Update** : On a newer version of WAMP, click the WAMP server icon > Apache > httpd.conf, then change the line Listen 80 to Listen 8080 or any port you want.

Answer (score 0):

1.Click on wamp icon >>

2.Appache >>

3.httpd.conf

4.Find this >>

```
           #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
           Listen 80
 OR
           #Listen 12.34.56.78:80               
           Listen 0.0.0.0:80
           Listen [::0]:80
```

5.Change all the "80" to "78" or any number double digit number.

6.Save the file. (ctrl + s).

7.Restart services. (Click on wamp icon. You will see the menu item).

8.Try on browser.